# MySQL: Huge increase in binary logging after a purge

Tags: mysql, logging, database-replication

I asked this on the MySQL forums, but didn't get any replies:

I've been manually running "PURGE BINARY LOGS TO" to purge the binary logs of a master DB for over a year now (1 slave DB on a different machine). After my most recent purge, over the next few hours, it generated a huge amount of logs - about 8 files of 1 GB each. Normally, it would take days before one 1GB file would be created. I did another purge that day and restarted mysql and it has returned to normal. What could have caused this? Is there anything I should be concerned about right now?

I can't remember the exact number of the purge command and it is now gone from history since I restarted mysql, but I think it was:

PURGE BINARY LOGS TO 'mysql-log.000101';

Thanks for any insight into this.